# Shell | removing repetitive lines

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sh

I need to write a Bash script for removing similar lines from an output file.
My output file is always same.

Lines 1 & 2 should stay and other lines similar to these two need to be deleted.

```
1:  </UsageData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2:  <UsageData broadcastday="2016-03-16">
```

The date varies.

The last line should be kept. E.g.

`</UsageData>`

I'm new to shell programming and I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my sample XML:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <UsageData broadcastday="2016-03-16"> 
>     <Hh hhID="48800301"> 
>         <Inst instID="000002B9"/> 
>         <Live> 
>             <Station>516</Station> 
>             <From>Wed Mar 16 2016 09:52:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)</From> 
>             <DurSec>58077</DurSec> 
>             <Viewer> 
>                 <HhMem>569de65c9c3ab0cf7bfa2df2</HhMem> 
>             </Viewer> 
>         </Live> 
>     </Hh> 
>     <Hh hhID="46920403"> 
>         <Inst instID="000002A8"/> 
>         <Live> 
>             <Station>5000</Station> 
>             <From>Wed Mar 16 2016 12:42:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)</From> 
>             <DurSec>47908</DurSec> 
>             <Viewer> 
>                 <HhMem>56caee95f915e09335fd976f</HhMem> 
>             </Viewer> 
>         </Live> 
>     </Hh> 
> </UsageData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <UsageData broadcastday="2016-03-16"> 
>     <Hh hhID="15260304"> 
>         <Inst instID="000000A5"/> 
>         <Live> 
>             <Station>5000</Station> 
>             <From>Wed Mar 16 2016 12:57:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)</From> 
>             <DurSec>28814</DurSec> 
>             <Viewer> 
>                 <HhMem>565f181dd830d3cc7057c0b9</HhMem> 
>             </Viewer> 
>         </Live> 
>     </Hh> 
> </UsageData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <UsageData broadcastday="2016-03-16"> 
>     <Hh hhID="50100501"> 
>         <Inst instID="0000022D"/> 
>         <Live> 
>             <Station>560</Station> 
>             <From>Wed Mar 16 2016 14:21:19 GMT+0000 (UTC)</From> 
>             <DurSec>41967</DurSec> 
>             <Viewer> 
>                 <HhMem>56c4412de6a8ff4da18fd4ae</HhMem> 
>                 <HhMem>56c4412de6a8ff4da18fd4cb</HhMem> 
>             </Viewer> 
>         </Live> 
>     </Hh> 
> </UsageData><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <UsageData broadcastday="2016-03-16"> 
>     <Hh hhID="36110404"> 
>         <Inst instID="00000104"/> 
>         <Live> 
>             <Station>545</Station> 
>             <From>Wed Mar 16 2016 15:01:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)</From> 
>             <DurSec>671</DurSec> 
>             <Viewer> 
>                 <HhMem>568ce8acbd0e486a951d41ce</HhMem> 
>                 <HhMem>568ce8acbd0e486a951d41dc</HhMem> 
>                 <HhMem>568ce8acbd0e486a951d41c5</HhMem> 
>             </Viewer> 
>         </Live> 
>     </Hh> 
> </UsageData>
> ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! First, I agree with @123 an XML parser (or XSLT) is a better choice. However, if you want help debugging your script we need to see your script! Please add it to the question. You can cut down your XML to the essentials, we don't need the full file.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add "solved".  The way to mark something as solved is to accept an answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it so that it turns green. You may have to wait a while before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with VERY easy way.

> awk  '/</UsageData><\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>/
>   {getline; next}1' file

Comment: All that Bash love, and then using awk instead of Bash? ;)